# How are memory addresses assigned in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I've learnt that the values of an array are stored "side by side" in terms of memory addresses such that the name of the array is a pointer to the first value of the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
    printf("%d", *array);       // The first value of array: 1
    printf("%d", *(array + 1)); // The second value of array: 2

}
```

Intuitively, I thought that variables declared in the code one after another were simply assigned neighbouring memory addresses. This idea goes against how an array is defined in memory, as all variables in my code would then make up one large array.

My question is, essentially, is there a way to know what the address of a variable is, relative to the other variables defined in my program, without, say, printing its address?

Comment: You're using an array, so all elements of the array are sequential in memory. However, with (e.g.): `int main(void) { int a,b,c; }` they can be in any order and even non-contiguous.

Comment: It has to do with the *Array*. In C/C++, you are guaranteed that elements in an array are sequential in memory. The bytes of allocated blocks will also be sequential. There are no other guarantees. Where an address lives also depends on the type or qualified type. Objects with automatic storage duration are declared on the program stack. `static` or `global` objects are stored elsewhere as are objects with *allocated storage duration*.

Comment: This is more about the behavior compiler and runtime than the language, which has no definite answer as their behavior is constantly envolving. The language simply tells you shouldn't care(e.g. calculating the address difference of variables that are not part of the same array or struct is not allowed).

Comment: Re “This idea goes against how an array is defined in memory, as all variables in my code would then make up one large array”: That is a *non sequitur*. The fact that elements of an array are adjacent in memory does not imply other things may not be adjacent in memory anymore than the fact that I paint my house white means you may not paint your house white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Intuitively, I thought that variables declared in the code one after another were simply assigned neighbouring memory addresses.

The C compiler converts your code (designed for "the C abstract machine") into whatever happens to create the same behavior in a completely different language (e.g. machine code for the target CPU).

As part of this "conversion to something radically different" local variables often cease to exist (replaced by registers that don't have a memory address because registers aren't memory) and even when they do exist they can be in any order, or overlap (e.g. same memory used for 2 different local variables that are used at different times).

Arrays are "more special" because they're typically larger and harder for compilers to optimize (while complying with the rules of the language that define the abstract machine's behavior); so it's a lot more likely that elements of an array remain contiguous in memory; but this is not a guarantee of any kind.

For an example, consider this code:

```
int foo(int bar) {
    int myArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4};

    if(bar < 0) return bar + myArray[0];
    if(bar > 0) return bar + myArray[2];
    return bar + myArray[1];
}
```

If you compile this (like I did using godbolt at https://godbolt.org/ ) and examine the output, you might see something like this:

```
foo(int):
  test edi, edi
  js .L6
  lea eax, [rdi+3]
  mov edx, 2
  cmove eax, edx
  ret
.L6:
  lea eax, [rdi+1]
  ret
```

As you can see; the array no longer exists at all (and none of the arrays elements have a memory address), because in this case the compiler was smart enough to optimize.

The same thing happens to your code (the array no longer exists and has no addresses at all). It becomes this:

```
.LC0:
  .string "%d"
main:
  sub rsp, 8
  mov esi, 1                  // The value "1" originally came from the array
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
  xor eax, eax
  call printf
  mov esi, 2                  // The value "2" originally came from the array
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
  xor eax, eax
  call printf
  xor eax, eax
  add rsp, 8
  ret
```

> My question is, essentially, is there a way to know what the address of a variable is.

Essentially; no. This is like feeding a horse carrots and then trying to determine where molecules of the original carrot will end up after the horse poops.

The only thing you can do is get the address at run-time (e.g. using `&variable`), which (if and only if the compiler can't prove that the code to get the address can be discarded/ignored) has the side-effect of forcing the compiler to make sure that the variable actually does have an address.

Comment: This is not really a correct answer because it uses a model of “how a C program is actually implemented,” but the question was asked in the model of “how C program semantics are described in the C standard.” Notably, the C standard **defines** an array as “a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects” (C 2018 6.2.5 20), and the question is posed using this as a basis. Answering that arrays are not necessarily implemented as contiguous objects in memory does not answer the question about what the C semantics are.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: No. The question is obviously talking about what happens after C is transformed (e.g. memory addresses and stack layout after compiling); where the standard's "as if rule" influences every other part of the standard; such that "arrays are defined as contiguous objects" actually means "arrays are defined as if they were contiguous objects in the C abstract machine but may not be after compiling".

Comment: There is nothing in the question that indicates it is asking anything outside the C model. Every word in it is consistent with semantics inside the C model (within OP’s stated beliefs).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Memory addresses (not pointers) of local variables (on the stack that does not exist)?

Comment: Yes. The C standard uses “memory” and “address” many times in discussing storage locations in its model, and the question does not contain the word “local.”